# how to receive json objects in the url page which was sent by jquery ajax call?

Tags: php, json, ajax

In the code below, i am sending color-'black' to 'process.php' page. how to fetch 'black' in the 'process.php' page

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "process.php",
     data:{color:"black"};,  
     success:function(data, status){  $("div").text(data);  }
  });
```

});

Comment: You send `'blue'`. And your answer is `$_POST['color']`

Comment: Maybe he's colorblind? :-)

Comment: Don't think about it too hard. AJAX is still **JUST** an http request. It shows up at the server exactly the same as any OTHER http request, and you access data in that request the same way as well.